# Do side effect if observable has not emitted a value within X amount of time

Tags: rxjs

I'm working on a use case that requires that if an observable has not emitted a value within a certain amount of time then we should do some side effect.

To give a practical use case:

- open web socket connection
- if no message has been sent/received within X time then close web socket connection and notify user

This requires for a timer to be initiated on every emitted value and upon initial subscription of observable which will then run some function after the allotted time or until a value is emitted in which the timer resets. I'm struggling to do this the Rx way. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can I clarify - 'if an observable has not emitted a value' doesn't seem to fit with 'timer to be initiated on every emitted value'.

Answer (score 8):

[`debounceTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) is the operator you're looking for: it only emits a value if no others follow within a specific timeout. Listening for the first message of the `debounce`d stream will let you time out and clean up your websocket connection. If you need to time out starting from the opening of the stream, you can simply `startWith`. Concretely:

```
messages$.startWith(null)
         .debounceTime(timeout)
         .take(1)
         .subscribe(() => { /* side effects */ });
```

---

**Edit:** if instead you're looking to end the a message stream entirely when it times out (e.g. you clean up in the onComplete handler), just cram `debounceTime` into a `takeUntil`:

```
messages$.takeUntil(
  messages$.startWith(null)
           .debounceTime(timeout)
).subscribe(timeout_observer);
```

With a `timeout_observable: Observer<TMessage>` that contains your cleanup onComplete.

Comment: All message will get ignored until time out though

Comment: @FanCheung The point is that this stream is solely used to handle your timeout behavior, and anything else hooks straight into `messages$`.

Comment: putting source observable inside stream triggered by source observable, are there any tutorial you can point me to this specific technique.

Comment: I tried your solution , works very well. should mark as good answer

Comment: @FanCheung I wouldn't call it a technique on its own because there are quite a lot of ways you can reuse the stream to derive new behavior. Sometimes there are race conditions, mostly if you pair items expecting them to come from the same item in the source. Sometimes you have to worry about refcounts (although operators on Observables tend to clean up nicely). When enforcing a loose policy like "timeout after x to free resources", races then aren't so important.

Comment: Only afraid will be more error prone and when there is error it gets very hard to debug? Maybe i ask it as a proper question

Comment: Shouldn't the appropriate operator be debounceTime rather than debounce?

Comment: @SamElliottDeLaTorreBabá Ah yes, good catch. Looks like the ReactiveX docs also hasn't updated its JS example!

Comment: I also think the side effects should go in the onComplete handler of subscribe. Testing now this way and it seems to work as needed.

Comment: @SamElliottDeLaTorreBabá ha, I had even when it down just above the code sample; updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with `race`:

```js
timer(5000).race(someSource$)
  .subscribe(notifyUser);
```

If `someSource$` notifies faster than `timer(5000)` (5 seconds), then `someSource$` "wins" and lives on.

If you only want one value from `someSource$`, you can obviously have a `take(1)` or `first()` on `someSource$` and that will solve that issue.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Best Answer! Race is exactly the right function for the use case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the perfect answer but it does what you asked, it depends on how you want to disconnect, there might be some variation to be done

```js
const source = new Rx.Subject();
const duration = 2000;

source.switchMap(value=>{
  return Rx.Observable.of(value).combineLatest(Rx.Observable.timer(2000).mapTo('disconnect').startWith('connected'))
}).flatMap(([emit,timer])=>{
  if(timer=='disconnect'){
    console.log('go disconnect')
  return Rx.Observable.throw('disconnected')
  }
  return Rx.Observable.of(emit)
})
//.catch(e=>Rx.Observable.of('disconnect catch'))
.subscribe(value=>console.log('subscribed->',value),console.log)

setTimeout(() => source.next('normal'), 300);
setTimeout(() => source.next('normal'), 300);
setTimeout(() => source.next('last'), 1800);
setTimeout(() => source.next('ignored'), 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A timer is initiated on each element and if it takes 4 seconds to be shown, then it will timeout and you can execute your function in the catchError

Here an example, it displays **aa** at T0s, then **bb** at t3s, then timeout after 4 second because the last one **cc** takes 10s to be displayed

```
import './style.css';
screenLog.init()

import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { race } from 'rxjs/observable/race';
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { groupBy, mergeMap, toArray, map, reduce, concatMap, delay, concat, timeout, catchError, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

// simulate a element that appear at t0, then at t30s, then at t10s
const obs1$ = of('aa ');
const obs2$ = of('bb ').pipe(delay(3000));
const obs3$ = of('cc ').pipe(delay(10000));


const example2 = obs1$.pipe(concat(obs2$.pipe(concat(obs3$))), timeout(4000), catchError(a => of('timeout'))); // here in the catchError, execute your function

const subscribe = example2.subscribe(val => console.log(val + ' ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()));
```