# How to get a stream of actions, until there are no actions emitting for X number of seconds

Tags: redux, rxjs, observable

I have a specific use case where I have a stream of actions coming in;
the example of use case is something like the following:

```
var someObserver = function(input) {
// ... some processing
    store.dispatch({ type: "SOME_CONTINUOUS_ACTION", value: input });
};
```

1. A stream of actions will be fired inside a handler, where the handler will be accepting a list of inputs in some sequence.
2. This action will be continuously streamed at an interval of **x** milliseconds. Basically, once all inputs have come in, the `Observable` shall terminate after waiting **N** seconds (which is significantly bigger than x milliseconds) from the **most recent** `SOME_CONTINUOUS_ACTION` being fired.
3. After that termination, I don't want any actions being watched.

How can perform this? I have a specific chat-application I am building, and I am trying to accumulate all the messages that are being processed by `newMessageHandler`, until `newMessageHandler` doesn't receive any more messages for **N** seconds.

Comment: You could use a variable that keeps track of the time the most recent message came in. And then use takeWhile to continue accepting messages as long as the time diff between when the current observable arrived vs. when the previous observable arrived is less than N

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do side effect if observable has not emitted a value within X amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940781/do-side-effect-if-observable-has-not-emitted-a-value-within-x-amount-of-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **timeout** operator:

```
source.timeout(N * 1000).subscribe(someObserver);
```

This will throw a TimeoutError when no message is emitted within N seconds.

In your case, it shouldn't be considered as error. It should just complete the stream:

```
source
  .timeout(N * 1000)
  .catch(e => {
    if (e instanceof Rx.TimeoutError) return Rx.Observable.empty();
    throw e;
  })
  .subscribe(someObserver);
```